# Time series: $Y_t = X_t - \mu$ is $AR(2)$

Tags: time-series

A problem says: "there is a time series $Y_t = X_t - \mu$  $AR(2)$ ..."

I'm a little bit lost here. If it's $AR(2)$, where are is the $x_{t-1}$ and $x_{t-2}$ terms?

Comment: Hard to say without more data, but I'd guess that is to say that $X_t$ is AR(2) (but you are not told the AR parameters) and that $Y_t$ is the same, with zero mean (I'm guessing that $\mu =E(X_t)$)

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a demeaned process. You have:
$$
X_t=c+\phi_1 X_{t-1}+\phi_2 X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t
$$
where $E(X_t)=\mu\neq0$. You can transform this to a zero-mean process by subtracting $\mu$:
$$
X_t-\mu=c+\phi_1 X_{t-1}+\phi_2 X_{t-2}+\epsilon_t-\mu
$$
which means that $E(X_t-\mu)=\mu-\mu=0$. Now we simply call the demeaned process $Y_t$:
$$
Y_t\equiv X_t-\mu
$$
and $Y_t$ is an AR(2) process as well.